# Privacy setting on Facebook for downloading pictures?

Tags: facebook, privacy, images, download

Facebook recently moved me to the new image viewer, which shows a download link below every picture.
With this download link it is possible to download full-resolution original images. I suppose the default is that only the uploader of an image can redownload the original, but I wouldn't mind sharing full versions of *certain* images directly through Facebook.

On my newest picture, for example,
`Right-click > Save as...` offers me:   ***185715***_182979465077370_115238648518119_369265_7842179_***n***.jpg (***53KB***)
`Download` gets me:
***172951***_182979465077370_115238648518119_369265_7842179_***o***.jpg (**363KB**)

Is there some way to control who can and cannot download my original pictures?

> [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Even if there was a option it would be effectively useless as the user can just right click over the image and save the image using the browser context menu. However, this would be the image as displayed rather than the higher resolution image you might have uploaded.

I've just checked and Facebook doesn't mess with the context menu.

Comment: Not entirely true, since the downloadable version is a full-resolution image, as opposed to the scaled-down version someone would get when downloading the version shown there.

Comment: @oKtosiTe you are mistaken. It is the *same* image. Look at the urls when downloading. To re-assure yourself : download both ways and compare the metadata. The download option was always there , Facebook just made it easier than "Save Image As"

Comment: As much as I hate to go in debate with a diamond moderator, I know I'm not wrong here. Presumably one can only download full versions of one's own images, quite possibly only ones uploaded quite recently. Facebook wouldn't serve me a 3MB, 2400x1800 file through the image viewer, now would they? @Philippe

Comment: To prove my point, I tried this again on my newest picture. Right-click, save as offered me 185715_182979465077370_115238648518119_369265_7842179_n.jpg (53KB) while download offered me 172951_182979465077370_115238648518119_369265_7842179_o.jpg (363KB). Please take note of the **last** character in both filenames (before .jpg). @Philippe

Comment: @oKto No they would not serve a 3MB file they would give you the optimized version as _n. I think this only holds for images that are served above some cap size (e.g. 3MB files). Maybe there is a cap that optimizes for large files with _n and has the original as _o . If the picture is under the cap then _n and _o are the same. So the answer to your original question stays the same... if one can see your image (by link _n.jpg) they can download the original by just changing the last char to o.

Comment: @Philippe: No, the first 6 digits are different also.

Comment: my mistake then