# How to download a Facebook cover photo in full resolution?

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos, facebook-profile

I got tagged in a picture, and would like to download it in full resolution (to print it because it is a nice picture of the whole soccer team).

PROBLEM: The picture has been uploaded as a Cover Photo, so the usual "Download" option does not appear:

[image]

[image]

What are my options to download the best-possible-resolution of the image?

I can always right-click and use the "Save Image" feature of the browser, but that downloads the low-resolution version of the picture (for big pictures, only a low-resolution version is sent to the browser, see dicussion in the comments [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/12933/1374)).

Comment: How about **Enter Fullscreen** and then take a screenshot?

Comment: Are you running any specific extensions or plugins that could block it? The `Download` option is still available on all images on Facebook. Just tested it.

Comment: It appears to me that 'Download' option is not available for photos posted by non-friends!

Comment: I don't use any extension. Indeed, it appears that even though I was tagged in that picture, the pic itself has been uploaded by someone I don't know. I reformulate the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image Download button does *not* appear *if* the image is a *Cover Photo* (in the 'Cover Photos' album). The Download button appears if the image is *not* a Cover Photo, even if it's uploaded by a non-Facebook friend.

The Chrome extension, [DownAlbum](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-fb-album-mod/cgjnhhjpfcdhbhlcmmjppicjmgfkppok?hl=en) or equivalent [User/Greasemonkey script](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/2180-downalbum) for other browsers like Firefox, will allow you to download the full-resolution version of images in the 'Cover Photos' album.

Comment: Well spot! The pic is indeed a cover photo.

Comment: I'm aware of this, but I'm not get it until now, so again why facebook not putting download option specifically for cover photos? what reason?

Comment: @TaufikNurRahmanda I don't know why. You should forward that concern to Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/help/feedback

Answer (score 1):

The `Download` button is still in use, but you will not be able to use it to download photos from "non-friends" that you have on Facebook. This is most likely more of a privacy style feature. To save a photo from someone you are not friends with you could do something like switching to full screen mode and right clicking and saving the picture. This will get you an image that is of a decent quality.

Answer (score 0):

You can get browser plugins that support downloading Facebook images, such as [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/photo-zoom-for-facebook/elioihkkcdgakfbahdoddophfngopipi?hl=en).